# convert list of slugs into json in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript function or npm package, which converts list of slugs into a json.

for example this is an input:

```
const data = [
  "/docs/faq.md",
  "/docs/index.md",
  "/docs/what.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-buy.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-store.md",
  "/docs/guide.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/analysis.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/index.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/tutorial.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/understanding.md",
  "/docs/start.md",
];
```

and this should be the output:

```
const output = {
    docs: {
        children: [
          { title: "index.md" },
          { title: "faq.md" },
          { title: "what.md" },
          {
            Tutorials: {
              children: [
                { title: "index.md" },
                { title: "how-to-buy.md" },
                { title: "how-to-store.md" },
                { title: "analysis.md" },
                { title: "tutorial.md" },
                { title: "understanding.md" },
              ],
            },
          },
          { title: "guide.md" },
          { title: "start.md" },
        ],
      },
};
```

another example:

```
const data = [
  "faq.md",
  "index.md",
  "/docs/what.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-buy.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-store.md",
  "/docs/guide.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/analysis.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/index.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/tutorial.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/understanding.md",
  "/docs/start.md",
];
```

and output:

```
const output = {
  children: [
    { title: "index.md" },
    { title: "faq.md" },
    {
      docs: {
        children: [
          { title: "what.md" },
          {
            Tutorials: {
              children: [
                { title: "index.md" },
                { title: "how-to-buy.md" },
                { title: "how-to-store.md" },
                { title: "analysis.md" },
                { title: "tutorial.md" },
                { title: "understanding.md" },
              ],
            },
          },
          { title: "guide.md" },
          { title: "start.md" },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I am not sure if a similar solution is available on Github or npm.

Comment: You do not have any `slugs`, just simply list of path's. Loop it and extract info with regex

Comment: try this package [flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten)

Comment: @Justinas no dude, this is list of [slugs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/#frontmatter-for-metadata-in-markdown-files) at least in my Gatsby project.

Comment: @EissaSaber thanks for response. It looks similar, but it's a bit different use case.

Comment: Also you structure is quite strange. It's not tree, so it's hard to implement

Comment: Your output starts as object where each attribute represents a path, but then the shape changes to each path consisting of an array of objects. Does it have to be inconsistant like that? For example what would the output look like if one of the slugs were `"something.md"` (without a parent)?

Comment: @Justinas each directory is inner attribute in output json (the order doesn't matter) and file is children of those. I don't understand what is strange about that.

Comment: It would be better to have like `docs.Tutorials.Foo.Bar.child: []` and `docs.child: []`

Comment: So your algorithm sounds like: `for each dir find in output if any of elements has key with that dir instead of "title". Recursive repeat for each dir except last element`

Comment: The structure is weird because the top paths look like this: `{ path1: [], path2: [] }`, but the inner paths look like this: `[{ path1: [] }, { path2: [] }]`. It's this inconsistancy that makes implementing this transformation hard.

Comment: @Justinas sorry for confusion. As I was writing my question I didn't include `children` attribute

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Sorry, you are right. I forgot to add `children` attribute into my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop your array, split on `/` and then just put elements in it's places:

```js
const data = [
  "/root-node.md",
  "/docs/faq.md",
  "/docs/index.md",
  "/docs/what.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-buy.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-store.md",
  "/docs/guide.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/analysis.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/index.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/tutorial.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/understanding.md",
  "/docs/start.md",
];

var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let parts = data[i].split('/');

  let current = output;
  
  for (var j = 1; j < parts.length - 1; j++) {
    let found = false;

    for (var k = 0; k < current.length; k++) {
      if (typeof current[k][parts[j]] !== 'undefined') {
        found = true;
        current = current[k][parts[j]];
        
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if (!found) {
      let newRow = {}
      newRow[parts[j]] = []
      current.push(newRow)
      current = current[current.length - 1][parts[j]];
    }
  }
  
  current.push({title: parts[parts.length - 1]});
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the path parts easily by iterating and splitting. Afterwards it's a little tricky to construct the tree efficiently, but this would work.

```js
const paths = [
  "/test.md",
  "/docs/faq.md",
  "/docs/index.md",
  "/docs/what.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-buy.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-store.md",
  "/docs/guide.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/analysis.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/index.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/tutorial.md",
  "/docs/Tutorials/understanding.md",
  "/docs/start.md",
];

const result = paths.reduce((tree, path) => {
  let parts = path.substr(1).split("/");
  let file = parts.pop();
  let pointer = tree;
  parts.forEach(val => {
    if (Array.isArray(pointer)) {
      let node = pointer.find(x => x[val]);
      if (!node) {
        pointer.push({
          [val]: []
        });
      }
      node = pointer.find(x => x[val])[val];
      pointer = node;
    } else {
      pointer = pointer[val] = pointer[val] || [];
    }
  });
  pointer.push({
    title: file
  });
  return tree;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Justinas Now yes, but you don't get an object anymore, but an array to make it work. Is that fine for you? It's quite different to your updated spec anyway. ;)

Comment: @Justinas You might also want to checkout this, since it's quite similiar to your updated spec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086927/turn-an-array-with-file-path-to-object-as-mentioned/53088248 EDIT: just noticed, that you're not the OP

Answer (score 1):

Having the `children` attribute introduces more consistancy to the structure of the directories object. Nevertheless, there is one more inconsistancy in this structure that manifests in the fact that the shape of a directory object is completely different from the shape of a file object.

To solve your problem as it is, I've added the following snippet which:

- Parses the slugs to split them into the sub-path elements (ommitting the first slash)
- Loops through the split element
- Calls a recursive mutating function that fills in the structure one by one

```js
const data = [
    "/faq.md",
    "/index.md",
    "/docs/what.md",
    "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-buy.md",
    "/docs/Tutorials/how-to-store.md",
    "/docs/guide.md",
    "/docs/Tutorials/analysis.md",
    "/docs/Tutorials/index.md",
    "/docs/Tutorials/tutorial.md",
    "/docs/Tutorials/understanding.md",
    "/docs/start.md",
];
const splitData = data.map((url) => (url.split('/').slice(1)));
const output = {};

function mutateRecursively(object, paths) {
    if (!paths || !paths.length) { return; }
    object.children = object.children || [];
    if (paths.length === 1) {
        object.children.push({ title: paths[0] });
        return;
    }
    const found = object.children.find((element) => (Object.keys(element).includes(paths[0])));
    if (found) {
        mutateRecursively(found[paths[0]], paths.slice(1));
    }
    else {
        const newBorn = { [paths[0]]: {} }
        object.children.push(newBorn);
        mutateRecursively(newBorn[paths[0]], paths.slice(1));
    }
}

splitData.forEach((paths) => {
    mutateRecursively(output, paths);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));
```

**NOTE:** Please note that the starting `/` is important, this approach only works properly on absolute paths. Also, you can notice where the structure inconsistancy manifests itself in the lines where I have to check if `paths.length === 1` to perform something different to the object.

**SUGGESTION:** To remove the inconsistancy completely, I suggest unifying the structure between directories and paths, something like the following:

```
const output = [{
    title: "src",
    type: "direcotry",
    children: [{
        title: "docs",
        type: "direcotry",
        children: [{
            title: "faq.md",
            type: "file",
            children: [] // or `null`
        }, {
            title: "Tutorials",
            type: "direcotry",
            children: [{
                title: "how-to-buy.md",
                type: "file",
                children: [] // or `null`
            }, {
                title: "how-to-store.md",
                type: "file",
                children: [] // or `null`
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    title: "some_root_file.md",
    type: "file",
    children: [] // or `null`
}];
```

Comment: If your suggestion is, what the OP is looking for, this could be marked as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086927/turn-an-array-with-file-path-to-object-as-mentioned/53088248